# Usage de « etc. » et « … » à la fin d'une énumération

Tags: usage, énumération

D'après Wikipédia, « etc. » a le même sens que les points de suspension dans le contexte d'une énumération.

Est-il d'usage, dans certaines situations, de favoriser l'un ou l'autre ? A-t-on une préférence dans le milieu littéraire ? Constate-t-on une évolution de leur usage dans le temps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Il y a une nuance :

- ***etc.*** est une abréviation typographique de *et cætera* du latin « et les autres choses » signifiant *Et le reste* (Le Robert).

L'auteur indique que l'on ne va pas imposer au lecteur la liste monotone de tout ce qui doit suivre si l'on veut faire un état exhaustif de la situation.

C'est au lecteur de compléter la phrase :

> Dans une trousse d'écolier, vous  trouverez une gomme, un crayon, une règle, etc.

- ***`...`*** sont des points qui suspendent l'intérêt du lecteur à la suite : on manifeste un silence ou une pause pouvant être peuplée d'interrogations, de suppositions ; l'imaginaire est là, mais pas de certitude :

> Il y eu un bruit... (ensuite l'oreille ne sait pas trop interpréter ce qui suit)  puis les pas se rapprochèrent... (souvent utilisé dans le suspense, les situations oniriques, etc. [ici *etc.* est soutenu, on aurait pu mettre des `...` car on ne cherche pas l'exhaustivité, mais on suggère différents états non certains, c'est un peu flou)  "Ah, c'est toi !"

---

***EDIT***

*Usage de cette nuance d'utilisation :*

- L'utilisation de *etc.* est soutenue, et surtout employée en littérature.
- L'utilisation des *points de suspension* se trouve aussi dans les énumérations et listes techniques ; elle est aussi passée dans les usages familiers.

Comment: Cette nuance n'est pas flagrante dans le contexte d'une énumération.

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse qui m'a aidé à y voir plus clair. (Je laisse encore un peu de temps aux autres membres avant d'accepter la réponse.)

Comment: @jlliagre Je pense avoir saisi la nuance, j'ai posté une réponse pour l'expliquer.

Comment: @jlliagre Elle a été précisée dans le second exemple : s 'il s'agit d'objets connus et que l'on peut dénombrer, *etc.* s'impose, s'il s'agit d'une liste ouverte (sur l'infini), ou si la solution dépend du lecteur, ou encore s'il y a trop de possibilités, les `...` sont plus naturels pour suggérer l'énumération.

Comment: @cl-r Mmmouais…

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai complété ma réponse pour tenir compte des usages

Comment: On verra bien si les votes négatifs me permettront un jour d'améliorer ma réponse... enfin, si on se réfère à la nétiquette du site, une explication semble souhaitable.

Answer (score 4):

Vos réponses m'ont permis d'y voir plus clair. Voici donc selon moi la différence :

## « … »

Dans une énumération, les points de suspension sont comme une invitation à compléter mentalement la liste. Le locuteur se devra de marquer un bref silence pour laisser à l'interlocuteur le temps d'y réfléchir. C'est l'idée de la suspension.

## « etc. »

À l'inverse, « etc. » sert à couper court à l'énumération, dans le sens où en citer davantage serait superflu.

Comment: « *etc.*  » pourrait avoir la même signification que « et j'en passe. »

Comment: et « … » aussi…

Answer (score 1):

Dans un usage courant aucune règle ne s'impose, tu peux autant utiliser l'un ou l'autre.

Answer (score 1):

- « etc. » du latin *et c(a)etera* signifiant « et tous les autres » est utilisé pour remplacer un nombre indéterminé d'éléments à la fin d'une énumération.
- Les points de suspensions « … » sont utilisés pour remplacer une portion de texte absente pour une raison ou pour une autre.

Le domaine d'utilisation des points de suspension est donc beaucoup plus large que celui d' « etc. » cependant, dans le cadre d'une énumération **écrite**, il n'y a pas de différence significative entre l'utilisation de l'une ou l'autre de ces formes ni de variation d'usage en fonction du niveau d'écriture. Les formes « etc. » et « … » indiquent simplement toutes les deux que l'on ne souhaite pas ou que l'on ne peut pas terminer l'énumération.

A l'oral, la différence est majeure puisque que seule la première forme est prononcée, normalement *et cetera* mais souvent de manière incorrecte « *exétéra* ».

On peut donc trouver indifféremment à l'écrit :

> Les entiers naturels sont: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.
>
> Les entiers naturels sont: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4…
>
> Les lettres des l'alphabet sont a, b, c, etc.
>
> Les lettres des l'alphabet sont a, b, c…

A l'oral, on indiquera au contraire le plus souvent de manière explicite la poursuite de la liste par *et cetera*.